# how do I replace text in a Visio vdx file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The Visio vdx files I'm using contain text (format = "#CANCEL[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f84f.jpg)") on the shapes. I am trying to find a way to replace that text with text from a structured list. I'm really new to programming and I'm not sure where to start. I know I need to open the file and I need to change the text, then I need to save it. Does anyone have a sure fire way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

my code is in C# please convert it into vb.net

```
string firstText = "Hello";
string secondText = "World";
PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
PointF secondLocation = new PointF(10f, 50f);
string imageFilePath = @"path\picture.bmp"
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file
using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10))
{
    graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
    graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
 }
}
bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
```